# MarketMarks app: How to perform Backup and Restore

Tags: google-play-store, backup, restore

MarketMarks is an excellent Android app to create a sortable wishlist for apps offered in the Android Play Store, complete with editable tags, update dates, prices, and custom notes.

I can't get the Backup and Restore functionality to work in it.  How do you get that functionality to work properly?

I want to be able to backup the MarketMarks list and then restore it.

Here's what I've tried, in order:

1. Select Backup
2. Select Restore
3. Select Check Updates

Each time I do this, MarketMarks crashes on step 3.

How do you accomplish this essential task?

Please specify the version of Android you used in your answer as well as the version of the Play Store (the Play Store version number is indicated at the bottom of the Play Store's Settings page, under 'Build version').

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An recent update to MarketMarks has fixed this bug, and it now works as expected.

Furthermore, the user can now customize the folder where the backups are stored.